# Why muslims aren't allowed to be a part of christmas gathering?

Tags: practical-islam

One thing I don't understand is why do they advise muslims not be a part of the gathering?

When in the end Allah knows best. My intention is never going to be to accept what the gathering is about. But I can be a part of the happiness.

Answer (score 1):

Bismi Allah Ar Rahman Ar Rahim.

In the name of God, the Most Gracious, the Most Merciful.

All Perfect Praise be to Almighty God,

and prayers and peace be upon the Messenger of Allah and his family and companions,

Having said that,

Peace be upon those who follow guidance

Islam is the religion of peace, love and happiness. and will never be in the opposite position of that

but being there -in that gathering- is accepting the idea of that gathering and sharing the belief of it.

> God Almighty said : ("The Jews and the Christians will not approve of
>   you, unless you follow their creed. Say, “God’s guidance is the
>   guidance.” Should you follow their desires, after the knowledge that
>   has come to you, you will have in God neither guardian nor
>   helper.")(Surat Al-Baqarah:120)

and being in that gathering is a basic part of their creed

and God knows best.